# Flow serious error occurred

Tags: visual-workflow

Cross post link to Dev forum: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G000000XhcxQAC

The issue is I'm unable to open my Flow, the parent flow which calls the sub-flow FaultFlow.

I've read multiple threads on this topic and the general concesis is this error comes about when some type of permission of a field has changed.  I don't feel that is my issue. There is a Sub-Flow which is being called.  That SubFlow opens just fine matter of fact it's a simple Email flow which I call, FaultFlow.  It appears, haven't confirmed, that when a day or several have passed we can open the parent flow.  We have determined when we 'inactive' the sub-flow, FaultFlow, the problem comes back.  Below is a screen shot of the Flow Debug Screen.

Secondly this is in a branch org, an dev org spun up from our packaging org giving it the same name space.  I'm unsure if that has anything to do with it but I'm throwing it out there.

This is my FaultFlow.  Very simple flow which takes the parameters of, event name, FaultMessage, and Flow Name to be used in an email.  That's it. No fields being accessed, just input parameters to add to an email.

[image: sub flow: Fault flow]
[image: Debug window of flow]